# Remove an item from TTK Combobox List

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, ttk

I am currently trying to figure out how to remove an item from a combobox dropdown list. 
Currently for my delete button I have the following code:

```
def prof_del_btn():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Doom.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    name=prof_input.get()
    c.execute("SELECT prof FROM profile")
    rows=c.fetchall()

    if (name,) in rows:
        delProf = c.execute('DELETE from profile WHERE prof = "{}"'.format(name))
        prof_input.set('')
        print('Profile {} has been deleted'.format(name))
        prof_input['values'] = (prof_input['values'])
    else:
        prof_input.set('')
        print('Profile Doesn\'t Exist')

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Please note, I was playing around with it and just cannot figure this out. 
Currently in my sql db I have "nat" and "two" under the profile and what I am trying to do is remove "two".

I am not currently using classes as I'm not too sure how to use them properly at the moment. How would I reload the list?

Comment: Actually you don't need to execute the SELECT statement before the DELETE statement.

Comment: I just tried that, however, if i don't have the SELECT statement, it won't recognise the value for the DELETE statement and go straight to the 'else' function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current `values` from the `Combobox` and remove the required item from the list and then update the `values`.  Also you don't need to execute the `SELECT` statement before `DELETE` statement.  Below is modified code:

```
def prof_del_btn():
    name = prof_input.get()
    if name:
        with sqlite3.connect('doom.db') as conn:
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute('DELETE FROM profile WHERE prof = ?', (name,))
            if c.rowcount > 0:
                print('Profile {} has been deleted'.format(name))
                options = list(prof_input['values'])
                options.remove(name)
                prof_input['values'] = options
            else:
                print('Profile {} does not exist'.format(name))
            prof_input.set('')
            conn.commit()
```